# Django ignoring REQUIRED_FIELDS

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a page with a registration and login function, however, I cannot seem to set fields as required.

My models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

     USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
     REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["first_name", "last_name"]

     objects = CustomUserManager()

     def __str__(self):
         return self.email
```

forms.py

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "email")
```

And views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.save()
            Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)

            return render(request, 'account/register_done.html', {'new_user': new_user})
    else:
        user_form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'user_form': user_form})
```

As you can see I declared first_name and last_name (I also tried to write them with a space instead of an underscore but it didn't help) as required.

However, I am still perfectly able to create a user without these features.

Comment: REQUIRED_FIELDS Just affects the behaviour of the createsuperuser management command. From the docs: “REQUIRED_FIELDS has no effect in other parts of Django, like creating a user in the admin.” https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.REQUIRED_FIELDS

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself by changing models.py to this:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_("first name"), max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(_("last name"), max_length=100)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [first_name, last_name]

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Comment: Yes, overriding the fields to not have "blank=True" is why that worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
REQUIRED_FIELDS
```

is only applicable when using the "createsuperuser" management command: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.REQUIRED_FIELDS

In order for those fields to be required they either need to be overridden on the model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=150)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["first_name", "last_name"]

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

(This has removed the "blank=True" argument from the fields' original definition: https://github.com/django/django/blob/ca9872905559026af82000e46cde6f7dedc897b6/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L340)

Or you can specify the fields as required in your form:

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = CharField(required=True)
    last_name = CharField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "email")
```